# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration resolve as module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

When running `npm run storybook` I got the following error.

```
 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\@testing-library\user-event\dist\utils\misc\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory  
      D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\@testing-library\user-event\dist\utils\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory       
      D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\@testing-library\user-event\dist\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\@testing-library\user-event\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\@testing-library\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules
        D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\@testing-library\dom doesn't exist
      D:\FullStack\UI\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\FullStack\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules
        D:\FullStack\UI\react-uikit\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@testing-library\dom doesn't exist

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.
```

All necessary packages seem to be installed. I reinstalled react-dom, but it didn't help.

Additionally providing `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-uikit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "jest": "^29.4.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

I tried reinstalling all the packages or create a new project but I am facing the same error. `npm start` & `npm run test` is working fine. Issue is only occuring when trying to launch storybook.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with some code I was taking out of a create-react-app project. I noticed the error was referring to `@testing-library/dom` not existing so I ran `npm install @testing-library/dom` and its working now.